# Product of two Ito processes

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am in the process of learning to use Mathematica for doing stochastic calculus.
I can do Ito's lemma by symbolic manipulation, substitutions, expansions and simplifications.

However, I feel like finding the resulting process of the product of two Ito processes should be possible using the inbuilt Ito functions. Meaning if I define Xt and Yt as Itoprocesses, is there a way to define the product and back out the drift and volatility terms?

```
(*Define the first Ito process*)
Xt = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
    Subscript[\[Mu], x]*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
     Subscript[\[Sigma], x]*x[t] \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, x[t], {x, 1}, 
  t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]

(*Define the second Ito process*)
Yt = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]y[t] == 
    Subscript[\[Mu], Y]*y[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
     Subscript[\[Sigma], y]*y[t] \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, y[t], {y, 1}, 
  t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]

(*Define the resulting Ito process*)
Drift[
 TransformedProcess[
  X*Y, {X  \[Distributed]  Xt, Y \[Distributed] Yt}, t]]
```

Comment: Look in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2519023/ito-multiplication-rule-for-jump-process  .

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of conditional probabilities for independent processes,  the distribution of a product (or any  other function ) of two independent variables is the integral over the density in $x$ of the first variable, multiplied by the probabilty of the other with the first variables fixed at $x$

$$Pr[ X Y < z]  == \int_{-\infty}^\infty \ dPr[ X < x ] \ * \ Pr[ x Y < z] $$

For two independent Wiener processes X, Y with N(0,t)-distribution one has

$$ Pr[ X Y < z] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \  e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}} \ \frac{1}{2}\ \left( 1 + \text{erf}(\frac{z}{2 x \sqrt t}) \right)\ dx $$

and the density

$$ Pr[ X Y \in dz] = \frac{1}{ 2 \pi t}\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \  \ e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\ t}} \ * \ e^{-\frac{z^2}{2 \ t \ x^2}}\ \ dx $$

Comment: This does not appear to address the OP's question, i.e. whether the result sought can be obtained using built in Mathematica functions.

Comment: As you may notice by the result for the trivial case,  there is no transformation to an  Ito process with scaled parameters, Observe the 1/x^2 term in the integral. The differential of the product process is trival, since 2. order differentials of X Y are zero